# MSB4019 Microsoft.WebApplication.targets when building .NET Framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: .net, msbuild

When i use

```
dotnet build
```

to build a solution with .NET Framework 4.7.2 project, i get the following error

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\
Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. 
Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" 
is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

In VS2019 the project builds correctly.
How to fix the path?

.NET Core 3.1 SDK is installed, I also tried to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK - without results